# Marking The Area objects in Sheets of Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I have been tried to get *Area* objects from *Sheets (3D Submission)* of *Revit* file through *Forge API*. Using this link `GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{guid of sheet}/properties` the *Area Information* isn't there, even though i have added the *area* in *sheets*.

My goal is marking the *Area* in 2D / *Sheets (3D Submission)*. How can i do that ?

The Area, i mean like this >> [marking The Area in 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKV4x.png)

Comment: What kind of area object do you want? I just test with Revit Room, and it works as well as I expected.

Comment: i have been edited my question Mr. @EasonKang

Comment: This looks like Revit Room or Revit Zoom. If your zoom or room is clickable on the Viewer, then you can obtain its properties via this API just like I replied to you from Forge Zendesk.

Comment: I put my steps to obtain the area parameter value of a room/area below, please have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area object looks like Revit Room or Revit Zoom. If your zoom or room is clickable on the Viewer, then you can obtain its properties via the API [Get Properties](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/). Here are a few steps I used to archive what you want, you can compare if there is something you missed.

1. Check the room/area elements are valid in your Revit sheet. A room/area should be enclosed by walls or `Room Separation`/`Area Boundary`.
   [image]
2. Make sure the sheet which contains your room/area is included in the set of the Revit `Publish Setting`
   [image]
3. Upload the well-configurated RVT to Forge for translation.
4. After translation was completed, load the sheet view (called `A102 - Plans` in this case) via Forge Viewer, and make sure that room/area elements in the view are clickable.
   [image]
5. Retrieve the `objectId` of selected room/area via `viewer.getSelection()`. The `objectId of the selected room/area in this view is`4089` for example.
6. Call API [GET :urn/metadata](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/) to get sheet's `guid`. Now it's `abdacd31-f94c-e84f-9a58-4663e281d894` for instance.

> ```
> {
>     "data": {
>         "type": "metadata",
>         "metadata": [
>             {
>                 "name": "{3D}",
>                 "role": "3d",
>                 "guid": "6bfb4886-f2ee-9ccb-8db0-c5c170220c40"
>             },
>             {
>                 "name": "A102 - Plans",
>                 "role": "2d",
>                 "guid": "abdacd31-f94c-e84f-9a58-4663e281d894"
>             }
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```

7. Call API [GET :urn/metadata/:guid](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/) to obtain instance tree of that view, and check if there is a room/area with the id we want. e.g. the room named as `Kitchen & Dining 101 [857279]` and id is `4089` in the API response.

> ```
> {
>     "objectid": 4084,
>     "name": "Rooms",
>     "objects": [
>         {
>             "objectid": 4085,
>             "name": "Bath 203 [857200]"
>         },
>         {
>             "objectid": 4086,
>             "name": "Bath 205 [857203]"
>         },
>         {
>             "objectid": 4087,
>             "name": "Bedroom 202 [857206]"
>         },
>         {
>             "objectid": 4088,
>             "name": "Entry Hall 201 [857209]"
>         },
>         {
>             "objectid": 4089,
>             "name": "Kitchen & Dining 101 [857279]"
>         }
>      ]
> }
> ```

8. Call API [GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) in this way to retrieve properties of the room/area. For example, `/modelderivative/v2/{YOUR_RVT_URN}/metadata/abdacd31-f94c-e84f-9a58-4663e281d894/properties?objectid=4089` and its response is shown as below, then you will see area which you want is showing in the response.

> ```
> {
>     "data": {
>         "type": "properties",
>         "collection": [
>             {
>                 "objectid": 4089,
>                 "name": "Kitchen & Dining 101 [857279]",
>                 "externalId": "e6ac360b-aaed-4c3b-a130-36b4c2ac9d13-000d1467",
>                 "properties": {
>                     "Constraints": {
>                         "Base Offset": "0.000 mm",
>                         "Level": "Level 1",
>                         "Limit Offset": "6500.000 mm",
>                         "Upper Limit": "Level 1"
>                     },
>                     "Dimensions": {
>                         "Area": "26.971 m^2",
>                         "Computation Height": "0.000 mm",
>                         "Perimeter": "29060.000 mm",
>                         "Unbounded Height": "6500.000 mm",
>                         "Volume": "118.317 m^3"
>                     },
>                     "Identity Data": {
>                         "Base Finish": "",
>                         "Ceiling Finish": "",
>                         "Comments": "",
>                         "Department": "",
>                         "Floor Finish": "",
>                         "Image": "",
>                         "Name": "Kitchen & Dining",
>                         "Number": "101",
>                         "Occupancy": "",
>                         "Occupant": "",
>                         "Wall Finish": ""
>                     },
>                     "Phasing": {
>                         "Phase": "Working Drawings"
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```

Hope it helps~

Comment: okay the problem is in **clickable** room/area..
thank you so much for your help

Comment: To make the room clickable, please make sure you have set up [Color Schemes](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2021/ENU/Revit-DocumentPresent/files/GUID-4809E31D-8385-4EB9-89C2-B58D7FB25B00-htm.html)