# How to Make a Revit Room Clickable in the Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm new to Revit, and I'm trying to access Room/Spaces data in a 2D sheet. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673202/marking-the-area-objects-in-sheets-of-revit), they note that the Room has to be clickable in the Forge Viewer. How can you make a Room clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the way I shared in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50697018/7745569), to make the room clickable, you also need to set up [Color Schemes](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2021/ENU/Revit-DocumentPresent/files/GUID-4809E31D-8385-4EB9-89C2-B58D7FB25B00-htm.html) for that 2D view.